# How can I judge the panel is up or down in the SlidingUpPanel component?

Tags: android

I use the **slidingUpPanel** open-source project in my recent project.Then,I must judge the panel is up or down.How can I implement it?
thanks your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`slidingUpPanel.getPanelState();`

Comment: I know this method,but I  need judge when the panel sliding.

Comment: okay then. you should set a listener via `setPanelSlideListener` and there is a method " onPanelExpanded"